# Restart of app is needed to get location

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Here is my `$cordovaGeolocation` plugin code

```
 function getLoc(){
  var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
        currentLocation = position;                 
        deferred.resolve(position.coords);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Error getting current location"+JSON.stringify(err)); 
        deferred.reject(err);
    });      
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

It shows error `{code: 3, message: "Timeout expired"}` when i run my app and location not already enabled. After app is opened and i enable location this show error.
To get the position once location is enabled, i hv to restart my app.

Comment: Where are you declaring `deferred` ?

Comment: inside  a function `getLoc()`